# How to change angle of AStar pathfinding

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, path-finding, a-star, 2.5d

- This is the effect of converting 2D to 2.5D. The coordinates of the points have been converted, but the AstarLine is still 'right angle', Is there anyway about, the astar pathfinding angle can be changed with anothor wanted angle?
- 2D mode: [normal pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwzMU.png)
- current: [current 2.5D pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4g9a.jpg)
- expect: [expect 2.5D pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ4JD.png)

Comment: has nothing to do with A*... depending on how you do things you can either just calculate the points for the turns of your connector lines before introducing that 45° turn, or if you have to do it afterwards (like drawing onto a picture that is already in isometric perspective), turn your coordinate system by the same angle your isometric perspective is turned... and then draw...  >_

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail before this question can be reasonably answered. As DarkSquirrel said, there's really no reason a\* should be affected by cosmetically changing how you're rendering a grid. A grid is a grid in memory, and that's what a\* runs on--you can show it to the user any way you want without issue. If your a\* is tied to display angles, there's probably a design problem. But again, impossible to say anything definitive without code and context.